# What are the ways to get from the US mainland to Vancouver Island with a car?

Tags: seattle, british-columbia, washington-state, vancouver-island, victoria-bc

I would like to take my car from Seattle to the south end of Vancouver Island, but I'm willing to drive to any ferry terminal. What are my options and how much do they cost?

Comment: All well and good, but off topic because [we are not travel agents](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents).

Comment: @ReddHerring I don't see how this is a travel agent question. There are no restrictions on date or times. I don't request a recommendation. Do you take issue with including a request for prices?

Comment: @AzorAhai You are still expected, as with everywhere on Stack Exchange, to demonstrate your initial attempts at research. A "ferry US to Vancouver Island" Google search returns 17,900,000 results for me.

Comment: @choster I wrote this specifically to self-answer. 18 million results sounds like something that would benefit from a question to sift through. Would you reopen if I edited research into the question?